# Is it possible to initialize Seam 2.3 component if the class is located in different EAR on JBoss 7.1.1?

Tags: jboss7.x, seam2

I have two EARs, EAR A is the actual application, EAR B is used for debugging and testing.

EAR A contains a JAR A with all Seam component classes, annotated with @Name. EAR A contains a WAR A which is Seam 2.3 webapp and defines all components in components.xml. This works fine.

EAR B contains another WAR B, which is a stripped version of the WAR A from EAR A. EAR B correctly defines dependency on subdeployment "JAR A" in jboss-deployment-structure.xml. WAR B defines only few components from JAR A, but they fail to initialize during the webapp deployment. This is caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component class must have @Name annotation or name must be specified in components.xml: [name of my class]
```

When I debug the initialization and set a breakpoint in Seam class org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization:488

```
        if ( !clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Name.class) )
        {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Component class must have @Name annotation or name must be specified in components.xml: " +
                    clazz.getName());
        }

        name = clazz.getAnnotation(Name.class).value();
```

The if condition is false. But when I inspect the clazz's annotations in debugger, I can see my annotation with the correct value.

```
interface org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name=@org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name(value=org.jboss.seam.security.identity)
```

I suspect this has something to do with loading the @Name annotation in two different deployments (i.e. classloaders), because when I move WAR B into EAR A, everything works. Please let me know if I am right or if there is a way how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the problem is caused by the fact that you have the `jboss-seam.jar` library in both WARs, this creates a classloading conflict because the `@Name` annotation is defined in both classloaders and the `isAnnotationPresent(Name.class)` fails because indeed the class does not have `WARB:Name.class` but rather `WARA:Name.class`.

To solve the issue, move `jboss-seam.jar` to a common ancestor classloader:

1. Move `jboss-seam.jar` into the lib directory of the server.
2. Put `jboss-seam.jar` among the EAR libraries and the two WARs in the same EAR.
3. Alternatively, drop the dependency between the two EARs, packaging the shared JAR in both EARs.
4. Finally, you can make the dependency in "the EE way", via EJB invocation to the services in EAR A.

In JBoss 7, there's a way of sharing modules among EARs, you could explore that solution too (this however is not EE standard behaviour so it is not portable to other containers). In the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` of EAR B declare the dependent modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="EAR_A.ear.JAR_A.jar" export="true" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I don't know however if this is worth it, it is easier to just duplicate the dependency in both EARs.

Also, note that if your components are in `src/hot` and you're in debug mode you will have problems using them from a separate WAR, regardless of the classloading you're using (components in `src/hot` exists in a separate classloader created by Seam when deploying the application, so the server knows nothing about those classes).

Comment: `jboss-seam.jar` is in both EARs. But seam application requires to have this one defined as a JAR module in `application.xml`. Moreover there is no common ancestor classloader in JBoss 7. But other than that you are right and the @Name annotations are loaded by two isolated classloaders and that is definitely an issue.

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional info. I think however that the least problematic solution is to just include JAR A in both deployments.

Comment: The dependencies are already defined exactly like that. 
Including the JAR A in EAR B works, however brings more problems. 
"Move jboss-seam.jar into the lib directory of the server" this simply won't work due to seam defined as ejb module in application.xml (that is how Seam works).
Creating JBoss 7 module out of seam won't probably work neither for the same reason.
The only working solution is actually to put WAR B into EAR A directly using exploded EAR A for simple manupulation...